# Wampserver error: Undefined variable mywampfp

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

Can't get Wampserver running.  Just installed it but get the following in **php_error.log**:

> [28-Jan-2009 10:13:17] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mywampfp in
>   C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php on line 252 [28-Jan-2009 10:13:17] PHP
>   Notice:  Undefined variable: i in C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php on line
>   252

Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try xampp. Personally I like it better and have had no problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isset` function to check if a variable exists before accessing it if you cannot be sure that this variable exists:

```
if (isset($mywampfp)) {
    // …
}
```

Same applies to elements of arrays, for example:

```
if (isset($_GET['mywampfp'])) {
    // …
}
```